# How to create an array of classes in jquery and with a 5 second interval, add and remove class switching div on dispaly

Tags: jquery

Good morning,

I am trying to create an array of classes and with a 5 second interval, I would like to add and remove class replacing the current div. This is for a carousel where I currently have the background image changing at this time. I would now like to make my descriptive text alternate in the same way. Can anyone help?

I was thinking an if statement checking the current background could work. Howver I get this error: 'unexpected token {'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

/* H E A D E R   C A R O S U E L */

```
$(function() {
    var headCarosuel = $(".headCarosuel");
    var backgrounds = new Array(
    "url('./img/backgroundVinny1.jpg')","url('./img/backgroundVinny2.jpg')"
    );
    var current = 0;
    function nextBackground() {
    $(".headCarosuel").css("background", backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    }
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    $(".headCarosuel").css("background", backgrounds[0]);

if(backgrounds = $("url('./img/backgroundVinny1.jpg')").css() {
    $('.headCarosuelText').removeClass('description2').addClass('description1');
}
else {
    $('.headCarosuelText').removeClass('description1').addClass('description2');
}

});
```

});

Comment: You must indicate what is the error in your code? What you expect and what you are vieweing. One thing could be toggleClass(c, cx), if you toggle to cx, later you must toggle that class so toggleClass(cx, cy) not (c, cy) because the object hasn't c class.

Comment: okay I have edited my code and question @Marc

Comment: `if(backgrounds = $("url('./img/backgroundVinny1.jpg')").css() {` you forgot a `)` after `.css()`

Comment: @Glubus thanks mate,, i now get this error : unrecognized expression:

Answer (score 0):

With your info and example I've understood the following code. It changes the background image and the background class every 5 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/* H E A D E R C A R O S U E L */
    var headCarosuel = $(".headCarosuel");
    var backgrounds = new Array(
    "url('https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=vinny1')","url('https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff&text=vinny2')"
    );
    var classes = [ "description1", "description2" ];
    var current = 0;
    function nextBackground() {
      var prevIndex = current;
      current = (current + 1) % backgrounds.length;
      $(".headCarosuel").css("background", backgrounds[current]);
      $(".headCarosuel").removeClass(classes[prevIndex]).addClass(classes[current]);
      setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    }
    nextBackground();
});
```

You can test it on https://codepen.io/mtomas/pen/MQXPGE